# How do I refine this code for an email signature?

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I am trying to create an email signature using html and an image I designed in Photoshop. I have sliced the image in PS and saved the slices out onto my PC. I now want to add links to certain slices and have managed to do this but the code is very messy and poor so I know that there is a better way to do it. I have attached the code below.

The links are not the actual links and are just placeholders for now. I also know that I need to save the images externally and will get round to it but just want to try and get the code sorted for now. I also understand that the image size is massive for an email signature so can I just add a "max-width" and "max-height" to the code to size it down or do I have to individually change all the sizes of each slice?

Finally, will this a spliced html image display well as an email signature or, because there are so many images attached to it, will it just go straight into spam?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
  div {
    position: absolute;
  }
</style>

<head></head>

<body>
  <a href="" />
  <div style="background-image:url('img/img1.jpg'); left:0px; top:0px; width:2000px; height:122px"></div>
  <a href="" />
  <div style="background-image:url('img/img2.jpg'); left:0px; top:122px; width:124px; height:222px"></div>
  <a href="https://www.linkedin.com" />
  <div style="background-image:url('img/img3.jpg'); left:124px; top:122px; width:866px; height:198px"></div>
  <a href="" />
  <div style="background-image:url('img/img4.jpg'); left:990px; top:122px; width:1010px; height:102px"></div>
  <a href="" />
  <div style="background-image:url('img/img5.jpg'); left:990px; top:224px; width:246px; height:576px"></div>
  <a href="https://www.bing.com" />
  <div style="background-image:url('img/img6.jpg'); left:1236px; top:224px; width:630px; height:120px"></div>
  <a href="" />
  <div style="background-image:url('img/img7.jpg'); left:1866px; top:224px; width:134px; height:576px"></div>
  <a href="" />
  <div style="background-image:url('img/img8.jpg'); left:124px; top:320px; width:866px; height:24px"></div>
  <a href="" />
  <div style="background-image:url('img/img9.jpg'); left:0px; top:344px; width:122px; height:456px"></div>
  <a href="https://www.google.com" />
  <div style="background-image:url('img/img10.jpg'); left:122px; top:344px; width:540px; height:150px"></div>
  <a href="" />
  <div style="background-image:url('img/img11.jpg'); left:662px; top:344px; width:328px; height:456px"></div>
  <a href="" />
  <div style="background-image:url('img/img12.jpg'); left:1236px; top:344px; width:630px; height:42px"></div>
  <a href="" />
  <div style="background-image:url('img/img13.jpg'); left:1236px; top:386px; width:48px; height:414px"></div>
  <a href="https://www.bing.com" />
  <div style="background-image:url('img/img14.jpg'); left:1284px; top:386px; width:482px; height:56px"></div>
  <a href="" />
  <div style="background-image:url('img/img15.jpg'); left:1766px; top:386px; width:100px; height:414px"></div>
  <a href="" />
  <div style="background-image:url('img/img16.jpg'); left:1284px; top:442px; width:482px; height:42px"></div>
  <a href="" />
  <div style="background-image:url('img/img17.jpg'); left:1284px; top:484px; width:62px; height:316px"></div>
  <a href="https://www.linkedin.com" />
  <div style="background-image:url('img/img18.jpg'); left:1346px; top:484px; width:94px; height:90px"></div>
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com" />
  <div style="background-image:url('img/img19.jpg'); left:1440px; top:484px; width:60px; height:82px"></div>
  <a href="https://www.twitter.com" />
  <div style="background-image:url('img/img20.jpg'); left:1500px; top:484px; width:94px; height:90px"></div>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com" />
  <div style="background-image:url('img/img21.jpg'); left:1594px; top:484px; width:92px; height:82px"></div>
  <a href="" />
  <div style="background-image:url('img/img22.jpg'); left:1686px; top:484px; width:80px; height:316px"></div>
  <a href="" />
  <div style="background-image:url('img/img23.jpg'); left:122px; top:494px; width:540px; height:30px"></div>
  <a href="" />
  <div style="background-image:url('img/img24.jpg'); left:122px; top:524px; width:2px; height:88px"></div>
  <a href="https://www.google.com" />
  <div style="background-image:url('img/img25.jpg'); left:124px; top:524px; width:418px; height:62px"></div>
  <a href="" />
  <div style="background-image:url('img/img26.jpg'); left:542px; top:524px; width:120px; height:276px"></div>
  <a href="" />
  <div style="background-image:url('img/img27.jpg'); left:1440px; top:566px; width:60px; height:234px"></div>
  <a href="" />
  <div style="background-image:url('img/img28.jpg'); left:1594px; top:566px; width:92px; height:234px"></div>
  <a href="" />
  <div style="background-image:url('img/img29.jpg'); left:1346px; top:574px; width:94px; height:226px"></div>
  <a href="" />
  <div style="background-image:url('img/img30.jpg'); left:1500px; top:574px; width:94px; height:226px"></div>
  <a href="" />
  <div style="background-image:url('img/img31.jpg'); left:124px; top:586px; width:418px; height:26px"></div>
  <a href="https://www.google.com" />
  <div style="background-image:url('img/img32.jpg'); left:122px; top:612px; width:406px; height:62px"></div>
  <a href="" />
  <div style="background-image:url('img/img33.jpg'); left:528px; top:612px; width:14px; height:188px"></div>
  <a href="" />
  <div style="background-image:url('img/img34.jpg'); left:122px; top:674px; width:406px; height:126px"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where are your `</a>` ? If there is no link no need to add an  empty link

Comment: Sounds like [`<map>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map) is a better solution

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks. That would help! It works quite well now but when I transfer it into Outlook to be made into a signature, it doesn't load at all. Wondering if it's because it uses "background-image" instead of "img"? Do you know anything about that? Also, "mad-width" doesn't work because it just changes the width of each individual sliced image to 400px max rather than the image as a whole. To fix this can I put the image in a container or something or do I have to individually change the size of each sliced image?

Comment: @vanowm Thanks for the suggestion but that looks quite complicated for my skill level. I am only a very basic coder (I even forgot to close my <a> tags as mentioned by mplungjan above).

Comment: That is no more complicated than what you are doing...all you need to know is coordinates of each section in the image and use `<area type="rect" ...>` to specify what to do with that area when clicked. You don't need to split image into separate images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Email is not web! Absolute positioning is an advanced trick that requires lots of hacks to work, and even `<div>s` are problematic, for Outlooks. Background images are also very tricky (there are plenty of answers on SO about these things individually).

Nobody knows all the spam rules, because otherwise people would subvert them, however, having so many links at the bottom of your message could easily be considered spammy. It's also risky because it's not normal. So I would advise against this method.

You will want to produce a HTML table, with `<img>s` (or just one image). However, best practice is to write out text in HTML, rather than have it in the image. I can't see the image so I can't give you sample code, other than something generic for a scalable image:

```
<body>
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x200" width="600" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;" />
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```